# No more VC6 versions of PHP 5.3.x?

Tags: php, apache

I need to install PHP 5.3.x (preferably x >= 4) on Windows box running Apache. Unfortunately, in the [PHP downloads page](http://windows.php.net/download/), I cannot find any PHP 5.3.x compiled with VC6. So...

- Can I use the VC9 binaries on Apache?
- If so, how? Do I have to do anything special?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=2743 - In this thread, they say that using VC9 PHP is not recommended at all with VC6 Apache, even though it might work at first. They don't say why.

http://windows.php.net/qa/ - Here, they also state not to use PHP5.3 VC9 with Apache compiled with VC6 (and also don't state why).

I think it might be best to upgrade your Apache to the VC9 version: http://www.apachelounge.com/download/

Comment: I have just installed the latest Apache. I don't know what version of VC it was compiled with (or even whether it was compiled with VC) though.

Comment: If it's a new install, I'd wager it was compiled with VC9 :)

Answer (score 3):

From the release announcement:

> Windows users: please mind that we do no longer provide builds created
>   with Visual Studio C++ 6. It is impossible to maintain a high quality
>   and safe build of PHP for Windows using this unmaintained compiler.
>
> For Apache SAPIs (php5_apache2_2.dll), be sure that you use a Visual
>   Studio C++ 9 version of Apache. We recommend the PHP builds as provided
>   by ApacheLounge. For any other SAPI (CLI, FastCGI via mod_fcgi, FastCGI
>   with IIS or other FastCGI capable server), everything works as before.
>   Third party extension providers must rebuild their extensions to make
>   them compatible and loadable with the Visual Studio C++9 builds that we
>   no longer provide.

http://www.apachelounge.com/download/

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.3.5 for VC6 server is still available: http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/

Comment: Thank you for that, as I'm running Window XP (It's a Corporate Computer) this is the highest version of PHP that is available to run on this platform.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure you can install the VC9 versions of Apache from http://www.apachelounge.com/download/ and they will work with the 5.3.x VC9 builds.