# Why can't I see windows binaries for PHP in the download page?

Tags: php, download, installation

I am trying to install PHP as an Apache module on my new Windows 7 machine. As per the manual, I am supposed to download VC6 x86 Thread safe binary for PHP 5.3 from http://windows.php.net/download/.  Strangely, I am not able to see VC6 binaries for PHP 5.3 on that page. VC6 binaries are only available for PHP 5.2.x series. The dropdown menu at the top does show the VC6 binaries for PHP 5.3 but nothing happens when I select that option. What am I missing ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No more VC6 versions of PHP 5.3.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346568/no-more-vc6-versions-of-php-5-3-x)

Answer (score 1):

**VC6 binaries don't exist anymore** -- it's been the case since **PHP 5.3.6**, which was released yesterday.

Quoting [**the announcement of PHP 5.3.6**](http://www.php.net/archive/2011.php#id2011-03-17-1) :

> Windows users: please mind that we do
>   no longer provide builds created with
>   Visual Studio C++ 6.
> It is impossible
>   to maintain a high quality and safe
>   build of PHP for Windows using this
>   unmaintained compiler.
>
> For Apache SAPIs (php5_apache2_2.dll),
>   be sure that you use a Visual Studio
>   C++ 9 version of Apache. We recommend
>   the Apache builds as provided by
>   [ApacheLounge](http://www.apachelounge.com/).
> For any other SAPI (CLI,
>   FastCGI via mod_fcgi, FastCGI with IIS
>   or other FastCGI capable server),
>   everything works as before.
> Third
>   party extension providers must rebuild
>   their extensions to make them
>   compatible and loadable with the
>   Visual Studio C++9 builds that we now
>   provide.

Answer (score 0):

check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs i currently use XAMMP on my win7 and it works fine