# PHP 5.3 - getting it to run on Apache server?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, webserver, php-5.3

I've set up my own Apache server; with MySQL, PHP and PHPMyadmin.

It used to work previously when I did it before on various computers; but that was the older versions I dealt with, not the latest. However, it's been a while since I've updated my PHP version, so that's why I'm asking this.

What configuration changes do I need to make to get 5.36 to work properly with Apache?

Currently any .htm files can display properly in http://localhost, but no .php ones.

All I see is a text file, so what's gone wrong with this?

The server is not public - in fact, it's on a Windows Vista Home Edition install, and it's a development one. I don't need to worry about anything else just yet, as this is a totally new install.

What config changes do I need to make?

I tried:

```
# mod_php5
Include conf/extra/suite-php5.conf
```

but that didn't work, so what's the solution with PHP 5.36?

Should I re-enable the above line (it's currently commented out with the # symbol).

So far the server works; but it's not serving up PHP pages, which is strange.

Anyone got any ideas why? I would gladly appreciate your help!

Won't post the httpd.conf since it's being developed right now though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No more VC6 versions of PHP 5.3.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346568/no-more-vc6-versions-of-php-5-3-x)

Comment: You could try something like WAMP or XAMP, which roll up apache, php, and mysql in a nice package without having to mess with installing them in each other.

Answer (score 1):

[No more VC6 versions of PHP 5.3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346568/no-more-vc6-versions-of-php-5-3-x)

> ```
> From the release announcement:
>
>     Windows users: please mind that we do no longer provide builds
> ```
>
> created with Visual Studio C++ 6. It
>   is impossible to maintain a high
>   quality and safe build of PHP for
>   Windows using this unmaintained
>   compiler.
>
> ```
>     For Apache SAPIs (php5_apache2_2.dll), be sure that you
> ```
>
> use a Visual Studio C++ 9 version of
>   Apache. We recommend the PHP builds as
>   provided by ApacheLounge. For any
>   other SAPI (CLI, FastCGI via mod_fcgi,
>   FastCGI with IIS or other FastCGI
>   capable server), everything works as
>   before. Third party extension
>   providers must rebuild their
>   extensions to make them compatible and
>   loadable with the Visual Studio C++9
>   builds that we no longer provide.

Answer (score 1):

Check your config files for http and php. I haven't done this in a while, but you need to add the file type .php to list of files types that you want Apache to serve. READ the config file carefully.

Also, inside your http config file there should be some additional lines that tell Apache where to find php, vis-a-vis the php.ini file. You need to set up your path information inside the config file and in the environment/system variables section of your Microsoft OS.